# How can I make my elements (img and video) 100% height and horizontally centered?

Tags: html, css, position

Here's what I have (1 and 2), and what I want (3).
http://i.imgur.com/aXmBDL7.jpg

The html is...

```
<div>
    <img id="ship" src="images/shipBG1.png" alt="" />
</div>
<video autoplay loop poster="images/void.jpg" id="video">
    <source src="video/Video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video/Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The CSS is...

```
html, body, { width: 100%; }

#video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    background: url(images/void.jpg) center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

#ship {
 margin:auto;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make these elements 100% height you must have its parents height set..
AKA

```
div {
   height: (your height)
}
```

this can not be a % unless its parrent has a set height like `html,body { height: 100%}` or an exact px

or

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

instead of having the div

To get (3) what i would do is give your image a `min-width` and give the parrent and `overflow: hidden;`